# How to get count of shares on Facebook for given Instagram Photo through API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

as everyone know, there is possibility to share photos on Instagram to Facebook. What I would like to ask you is if there is API way how to get number of such shares?

Any idea?

Thx for your tips in advance!

Jakub

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `/?id` (respectively `URL`) endpoint:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/url

meaning a request would look like

```
GET /?id=https://instagram.com/p/9q0-tUuSyL/
```

which returns

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "960618280676059",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-11-04T16:14:14+0000",
    "url": "https://instagram.com/p/9q0-tUuSyL/"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 13
  },
  "id": "https://instagram.com/p/9q0-tUuSyL/",
}
```